# Rails search by multiple tags using acts as taggle on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

At the moment when you click on a tag, it shows all tasks with that tag. What I'd like to do is make it so that once you click a tag, clicking an additional tag further filters the results with the clicked tag name.

Ex.

Cable (tagged with: tv, credit card. bills)

Chairs (tagged with: credit card, bills)

When I click on the 'credit card' tag after I click 'bills' tag , I'd like to have it display only those tasks which are both a bills tag AND and credit card tag.

Thanks for any help or suggestions

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629924/rails-acts-as-taggle-on-filter-by-multiple-tags/)  example but still when I click one tag it filters it but when I click on another tag it doesn't remember the tag that was clicked before.

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @users = User.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
get 'context' => 'users#index', :as => 'context'
get 'tag' => 'users#index', :as => 'tag'
```

index.html.erb

```
<% tag_cloud User.tag_counts_on(:tags), %w[s m l] do |tag, css_class| %>
   <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag:(tag.name), class: css_class) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: could you `print` `params[:tag]`?

Comment: params[:tag] returns basically whatever I click on so if i click on tv my params[:tag] returns 'tv'

Comment: I asked question above beacuse you should parse the `params[:tag]` string to array. `User.tagged_with(["credit card", "bill"], :match_all => true)` will match all users tagged with both `credit card` and `bill`.

Providing such functionality you should rewrite code for url which accepts tag param. 
e.g.: `url/?tags=tag1+tag2`  here `params[:tag]` is `tag1 tag2` string. you should parse them and put in an array then pass to `with_tagged` method. also in tag search page, you have to build new urls for chaining tag requests. e.g. `url?tags=tag1` => `url?tags=tag1+tag2` not `url?tags=tag2

Comment: I'm still struggling to chain tag requests can you please show me how that would look in my context. thanks

Comment: could you provide your url format? are they beautiful, like `/url/tags/tag1/tag2` or old school style like, `/url/?tags=tag1+tag2`

Comment: it looks like this for one of the tag `url/tag.Video?class=s&tag=Video` Btw I haven't been able to chain it like ` tag1/tag2/tag3` yet

Comment: try `link_to "Something", tags_path(:class => "s", :tags => {:tag1 => "foo", :tag2 =>"bar"})`. this will make your urls look like
`tags?class=s&tags[tag1]=foo&tags[tag2]=bar`. 

or add a hyperlink to one of your current pages like that: `link_to "Another thing", request.original_uri+'/&tags[tag2]=bar'` 

then in your controller function you have to parse this query.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
get 'tag/*tags' => 'users#index', :as => 'tag'
```